# Understanding coordinates in a plane

Tags: coordinates

I am learning animation. Position has two value, X and Y. X control left right, Y up and down.

So the tutorial am following: there the tutor positions the hands of a cartoon character in a way that they have the same Y value ($638$) and different X values ($733$ and $347$). (I attached the figure)

My question is if Y has same value, the hands should be in the same line, in an up and down manner right?

But in the tutorial that doesn't happen. The hands are sitting side by side.

I drew myself a graph, there I took $(x,y)= (3,5), (2,5)$, there I see both of them stay in same line in Y axis.

I must be thinking something wrong. What is that? If my graph makes sense then why I am seeing something different in the tutorial?

[image]

Comment: You said it yourself: “Y controls up and down”. So if two points have the same Y-value, they have the same up-and-down-ness. Then the only possible difference between the points is the X-value, which means they can have different side-to-side-ness, which is why you observe the “hands are sitting side by side”. Indeed, you should use Desmos like the other commenter suggested, because the graph axes seem to be flipped in your head.

Comment: It seems like you have $x$ and $y$ backwards at some point in your understanding! It sounds like the graph you drew isn't quite right. Here is a graph with dots at $(x, y) = (3, 5)$ and $(x, y) = (2, 5)$: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mptkqoas7q

Comment: It's surprisingly difficult to find a question about plotting $x,y$ coordinates on this site! You may find it helpful to search elsewhere on the Internet. [This](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/zdbc87h/articles/zvvmtv4) seems like a good refresher, for example. I think your misunderstanding may come from the fact that the $y$ axis is vertical, so it's tempting to think that "when the $y$ co-ordinates are the same, the points must lie on a vertical line". You're not alone in this misunderstanding, but that's just not how it works!

Comment: I could not thank you all who take time to reply me. I am about to cry. :'( I am spending hours to understand it, but cant. 
@ Benjamin Thank you

@Izaak Thank you so much for suggesting that site. I really needed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“$Y$ controlling up and down” means that points with the same $y$-value are the same amount up or down. Different positions, which are the same amount up or down, are side-by-side. This is what you observed in the tutorial. This is not what you did when plotting points yourself.

Comment: Wow... Thank you so much. It hreally helps me to understand it.